# Import csv with x y coordinates in QGIS 3 modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

In the modeller, I can't find a way to import a csv that has lat/long values and bring this in as a spatial file?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This workflow needs the csv-layer added into the layer panel before.

**QGIS 2.18 Workflow**

1. from Inputs you add a Table (Picture Nr 1. - 2.)
2. add "Points layer from table" (Nr. 4)

   2a. define x and y fields

   2b. define output-file
3. save and run model (Nr.5)

The steps aren't simliar with the screenshot, but the order in general is the same.

[image]

**QGIS 3.2.1 Workflow**

1. from Inputs / Eingaben add Vectorlayer / Vektorlayer
2. define name and set geometry type to not necessary / Geometrie nicht erforderlich.
3. add "Points from table"/ "Punktlayer aus Tabelle" tool and define x, y and output.

[image]